# How to append non const wchar array from given index in the array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to concatenate two* wchar arrays, but wcscat() requires const wchar_t source.I need to do something like this

```
 wcscat(strResultAbsolutePath, strRelativePath[i]);
```

but strRelativePath[] shouldn't be const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is not in `const`. Problem is, that `strRelativePath[i]` is `wchar_t`, not `wchar_t*`.
You should use

```
wcscat(strResultAbsolutePath, &strRelativePath[i]);
```

that means copy from `strRelativePath` beginning from symbol by index `i` to `strResultAbsolutePath`.